# Search Application Log for string based on timeframe with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, smtp

### UPDATED 10.11.2022

I added the timeframe parameters, but I'm getting an error message for an empty body.  How do I prevent this?

This is my current script:

```
$Subject = "EventLogAlert {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} on $env:COMPUTERNAME" -f (Get-Date)

$Server = "smtp.server" 
$From = "From@domain.com" 


$To = "SOMENAME@domain.com"
$Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "******" -AsPlainText –Force

#(Warning! Use a very restricted account for the sender, because the password stored in the script will be not encrypted)
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("From@domain.com" , $Pwd)

$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8


$EndTime = Get-Date
$StartTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)


$events    = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application";ID=400;ProviderName="ProviderNameGoesHere";StartTime=$StartTime;EndTime=$EndTime} |
             Where-Object {$_.Message -like '*StingToLookFor*'} |
             Select-Object -Property TaskDisplayName,ID,TimeCreated,Message -First 1


$Body = $events

Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -SmtpServer $Server -Body "$Body"  -Subject $Subject -Credential $Cred -Encoding $encoding
```

Error message:

```
At C:\ps\script_name:1 char:1

+ script name: script_name.ps1

+ ~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (script:String) [], CommandNotFoundException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.

At C:\ps\script_name.ps1:22 char:14

+ ... events    = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application";ID= ...

+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-WinEvent], Exception

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingEventsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventComm

   and

Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Body'. The argument is null or empty.

Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

At C:\ps\script_name.ps1:29 char:64

+ ... Message -From $From -To $To -SmtpServer $Server -Body "$Body"  -Subje ...

+                                                           ~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingValidationExce

   ption

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Send

   MailMessage
```

### ORIGINAL POST 10.10.2022

I'm a novice to PowerShell.  I'm developing a script to monitor the Application Log for a specific string.  The script below works, but I need help limited the timeframe to search for.  Right now it searches the entire log.  I only want to search for the last 15 minutes and only send an email if there is a match within this timeframe. The script runs every 10 minutes via the Task Scheduler.

Can someone guide me in solving this?

```
#Mail SMTP Setup Section
$Subject = "EventLogAlert {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} on $env:COMPUTERNAME" -f (Get-Date)
$Server = "smtp.server" 
$From = "From@domain.com" 

$To = "SOMENAME@domain.com"
$Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "enterpassword" -AsPlainText –Force password
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("From@domain.com" , $Pwd) #Sender account credentials

$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 


$events    = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application";ID=400;ProviderName="ProviderNameGoesHere"} | 
             Where-Object {$_.Message -like '*StingToLookFor*'} | 
             Select-Object -Property TaskDisplayName,ID,TimeCreated,Message



$Body=Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application";ID=400;ProviderName='ProviderNameGoesHere'} | Select TimeCreated,Message | select-object -First 1


Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -SmtpServer $Server -Body "$Body"  -Subject $Subject -Credential $Cred -Encoding $encoding
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this code into your script for setting start time, end time as well as passing them into get-winevent.

```
$EndTime = Get-Date
$StartTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application";ID=400;ProviderName='ProviderNameGoesHere';StartTime=$StartTime;EndTime=$EndTime} | Select TimeCreated,Message | select-object -First 1
```

Edit: to Address comment using try/catch. Now, when there are no results from get-winevent in the last 15 minutes, it will simply print that there were no results and not send an email in the console. If you want it to still send an email saying there was no events, then paste the send-mailmessage line in the catch block where write-host is and change the "$body" to simply read "no results"

```
$Subject = "EventLogAlert {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} on $env:COMPUTERNAME" -f (Get-Date)

$Server = "smtp.server" 
$From = "From@domain.com" 


$To = "SOMENAME@domain.com"
$Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "******" -AsPlainText –Force

#(Warning! Use a very restricted account for the sender, because the password stored in the script will be not encrypted)
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("From@domain.com" , $Pwd)

$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8


$EndTime = Get-Date
$StartTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)


try { 
        $events    = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application";ID=400;ProviderName="ProviderNameGoesHere";StartTime=$StartTime;EndTime=$EndTime} |
                    Where-Object {$_.Message -like '*StingToLookFor*'} |
                    Select-Object -Property TaskDisplayName,ID,TimeCreated,Message -First 1
        $Body = $events

        Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -SmtpServer $Server -Body "$Body"  -Subject $Subject -Credential $Cred -Encoding $encoding
    }
catch [Exception] {
        if ($_.Exception -match "No events were found that match the specified selection criteria") {
        Write-Host "No events found in last 15 minutes - not sending email.";
                 }
    }
```

Comment: I updated my script with your code, but I ran into another problem.  How can i resolve the error that I posted in my updated question?

Comment: The issue is that when you ran the initial get-winevent command, there were no results returned in the timeframe. This made $events have a value of null. since $body = $events, this made $body null and you cannot have a null body in an email so it says. The best option here is to write it in a try/catch block. See edit

Comment: Thanks.  Let me try this.  Where does the Write-Host go?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex write-host just prints the message to the powershell window. Change to:  `Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -SmtpServer $Server -Body "No Results"  -Subject $Subject -Credential $Cred -Encoding $encoding` if you still want an email

Comment: If there are no results I don't need any feedback.

Comment: Your code works!!! Is there a way to format the output message so the items TaskDisplayName, ID, TimeCreated and Message are displayed in either a list or table?  If you need me to open a new question I will.

Comment: You just want the table in the email? try changing the $body = $events line to instead read `$Body = $events | Format-Table`

Comment: I apologize for the delay in accepting your answer.  I had to wait for the system admin to text the script.  It currently works and we receive emails.  I still need to make some small changes to weed out a false positive, which I plan to do with this: `Where-Object {($_.Message -notcontains 'somestring') -and ($_.Messagee -contains 'somemstring')}`

Comment: Thanks again for your help on this question.

Answer (score 2):

Narzard's answer covers it, but another way to search by relative time uses xml XPath (which you can copy/paste from event viewer filters):

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Application -FilterXPath @'
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[
      EventID=400 and
      Provider[@Name='ProviderNameGoesHere'] and 
      TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 900000]]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
'@
```

XPath is way wordier, but lets you search event data properties like usernames